# Laravel: Only show "Cookie policy"-popup on first load

Tags: php, laravel

As with many other websites, I want to show a modal window on first page load to a user, saying that the website uses cookies. When the user dismisses the modal and makes a reload of the page, the modal should not appear again.

I'm fairly new to cookies in Laravel, and I know it can be achived with this. How do I achive this? I can imagine something with setting a cookie in the user's browser, and if it's present, I don't show the modal.

In advance, thank you.

Comment: "_setting a cookie in the user's browser, and if it's present, I don't show the modal._" Exactly

Answer (score 5):

Spatie creates awesome packages for Laravel developers. You may use this package easily.
https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-cookie-consent

Comment: I shall check it out :).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a mix of @Buraco's suggested package and my own styling of the dialog box.

Comment: if @Buraco answer help, please accept it or at least up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out our Package which gives you a lot of options but is also very easy to set up. https://github.com/42coders/eu-cookie-consent